# Scroll Down problems on mobile (Revolution Slider 6)

Tags: revolution-slider

I use revolution slider 6, I created a carousel type slider but on the mobiles I can't scroll down. I tried all possible variants and settings. I mention that I have to keep this format.
If you know a solution I look forward to it.
Thanks!

The slider can be viewed on www.homecity.ro